# Função de fatorial não retorna

Tags: c, algoritmo

Preciso usar função em C porém não está retornando o fatorial.

> Problema:"Dado um número inteiro n, calcule seu fatorial n!. O
>   fatorial de um número é dado pela equação:
>
> ```
> n! = n(n1)(n2) : : : 1. Por definição, 0! = 1.
> ```
>
> Você deve implementar a função:
>
> 1 /** 
>   2 * Funcao que calcula o fatorial de um numero n
>   3 * @param n um numero inteiro positivo
>   4 * @return o fatorial de n
>   5 */
>   6 unsigned long int fat( unsigned int n);
>
> Entrada O programa deve ler um número inteiro n. Saída O programa deve
>   apresentar uma linha com a mensagem: "n! = f", onde n é o número lido
>   e f o seu fatorial. Observações O fatorial de um número é resultado de
>   uma operação de produtório que pode levar a valores incrivelmente
>   grandes. Lembre-se de usar tipos de dados apropriados ao problema
>   proposto."

Meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long int fat( unsigned int n){
  int x,fatorial,resultado1;

  for(fatorial = 0; x > 1; x = (x - 1)){
    fatorial = (fatorial * x);
    resultado1=fatorial;
    }
    return resultado1;
}


int main(){
  int numero,resultado;

  scanf("%d",&numero);

    resultado = fat(numero);
  printf("%d! =  %d",numero,resultado);


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código é confuso, desorganizado e tem coisas demais. Mas o problema principal é a mistura conceitos sem critério. O enunciado demonstra o que tem que fazer. O fatorial é um número multiplicado uma vez seguida de outra por uma sequência de números. Esta sequência vai de 1 até o N especificado. Então o laço é muito simples, vai de 1 até N, está no enunciado. E a multiplicação é o valor inicial de 1 (a unidade básica) por esse valor sendo incrementado. Só isto.

Também havia um problema de formatação no [`printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Sugiro entender os mecanismos da linguagem de forma mais básica antes de usá-los. Digo, saber cada caractere do `for` e outras coisas. Porque está colocando cada coisa. Não faça nada sem critério, sem poder explicar porque está fazendo aquilo. Não coloque uma vírgula, um espaço sem que tenha um justificativa. O mesmo omitir certas coisas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long int fat(unsigned int n) {
    int fatorial = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) fatorial *= i;
    return fatorial;
}

int main() {
    int numero;
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    printf("%d! = %ld", numero, fat(numero));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZYqVRu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bemwjmbj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Fatorial.c).

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que fica mais facil assim: ele verifica a condição, se for verdade faz o que está a esquerda de ':'. Se não, então faz o que esta a direita de ':'.

```
//fatorial
int fatorial(int num){
    return (num>0) ? num*fatorial(num-1) : 1;
}
```